# Deriving buy 3 get 1 free formula

Tags: javascript, math

I would like to derive a buy 3 get 1 free formula, so for example:

```
Buy 1, pay price of 1
Buy 2, pay price of 2
Buy 3, pay price of 2
Buy 4, pay price of 3
Buy 5, pay price of 4
Buy 6, pay price of 4
```

Looks like it's like this:

```
1 - 0
2 - 0
3 - 1
4 - 1
5 - 1
6 - 2
7 - 2
8 - 2
9 - 3
```

and so on but I cannot formulate it to something like n - 1 blah blah.

Does anyone has a reference where I can refer to?

Comment: n ------- Math.floor(n/3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
totalPrice = Math.ceil(totalItems / 3 * 2);
```

for every 3 items you pay a price of 2. If you grab 1-2 extra, you pay full price for them.

Comment: __Note__: This works because `n % x = ceil((n % x) / x * (x - 1))`. `n` and `x` being `totalItems` and `3` here respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
totalPrice = (totalItems/3)*2+ totalItems%3
```

this should work assuming totalItems is saved as an integer.

Assuming the number of items is N, it can be written as:

> N = 3*M + L
>
> (L < 3)

M is the result of integer division, -mathematically the floor of the division-

L is the remainder of integer division.

the price is:

> P = 2*M + L

Answer (score 0):

The difference you displayed in the second table is exactly

```
totalItems/3
```

so the items to pay for are

```
totalItems-totalItems/3
```